# How to generate a UITextField and UIButton in UIScrollView and remove these items dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

HI stackoverflow friends

I have situation that when i click on a button it will generate dynamically a uitextfield with a remove button. If I don't need that text field then i click the remove button it will goes off.More over the user can generate infinite no: of these pair. So that I think it should be add in a scrollview. Is it possible this. Can anyone know how to do this?

Any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TableView cellForRowAtIndexpath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    UITextField* textField;
    if (cell == nil) 
    { 
      cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 
      textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,30,30)];
      textField.tag = 10; 
      [[cell contentView] addSubView:textField];
      [textField release];
    }
    else
    {
      textField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    }

    // Do something with TextField
    return cell;
}
```

You can just have one add button on the navigation bar across top right that would add to NSMutableArray addObject textField to it and reloadTable. Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath get objectAtIndex for that array and add to cell contentView. To delete the cells you can implement swipe to delete for cells...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     // If row is deleted, remove it from the Array.
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
     {
      // delete your data item here
     }
}
```

Comment: This code will create huge amount of text fields in each cell after some scrolling, as you create a new one every time cell gets reused. Textfield should be created with a tag inside the if statement, and accessed by `viewWithTag:` later.

Answer (score 0):

Posted some code that should help you:

```
// alloc + init + set appropriate size and origin
UIScrollView *scroll;
UITextField *field;
UIButton *button;
// add subview
[scroll addSubview:field];
[scroll addSubview:button];
// remove subview
[field removeFromSuperview];
[button removeFromSuperview];
// memory managment
[field release];
[button release];
```

Comment: "More over the user can generate infinite no: of these pair" -> So I would recommend using UITableView not ScrollView. TableView can reuse cells while scroll view doesn't have cell reuse concept.

Comment: You are right, but posted code will be too large. So I just show approach to work with scroll view